# Point Color not reported in deck.gl multilayer in Superset

Tags: apache-superset, deck.gl, multi-layer

In superset, I create a map layer with deck.gl Scatterplot chart and define categorical color for each point.
The color is define in dashboard properties

"label_colors": {
"Bus": "#F6DC09",
"velo": "#EB483C",
"voiture": "#8BC53E",
"Stationnement": "#0283C5"
},
This works fine, the color appears for each categorie in the maps
[deck.gl Scatterplot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgJnU.png)

but when I add this chart in deck.gl multilayer chart, there are just one color for all points
[deck.gl multilayer result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeCpy.png)

I expected that have the same result in the scatterplot and the multilayer.

I create a issue in github too: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/23259

Environment:
browser: chrome Version 110.0.5481.177
superset version: 2.0.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I try to clarify my problem. Hope it's better